# NSURLConnection Blocking UI

Tags: uiscrollview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsrunloop, blocked

I am trying to run an asynchronous NSURLConnection but its causing my UI to be blocked everytime i receive a response. I was under the impression that an async connection does not block the UI i have also setup a runloop so i can respond to incoming touch events.

Below is a snippet of the code

```
self.playerConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[self.playerConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]  forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[self.playerConnection start];
```

Any suggestions ?